# Relational division in SQL, but for my specific DB

Tags: sql

I am attempting to complete a homework assignment for my databases course, but I am having trouble with one of the questions. It asks to implement division (like in relational algebra) in a useful database query, but from what I understand, division is not a logical operator in SQL.

That said, I have seen ways people implement it, and I have absolutely no idea how I could accomplish that with regards to my database (while making a 'useful' query). If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Some links to information about my relevant database and supporting documents:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OMAOPS4Q7kU00AorBWG-0u8a30QHiqVO

I was asked to provide supporting data, so here is the definition for the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE passenger (
        passengerID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        name varchar(255), 
        address varchar(255), 
        sex char(1), 
        date_of_birth DATE,
        bank_account_number char(18), 
        checked_in binary(1)
);

CREATE TABLE roster ( 
        routeID_forRoster int, 
        departure_time TIME NOT NULL, 
        arrival_time TIME,
        FOREIGN KEY (routeID_forRoster) REFERENCES route(routeID), 
        CONSTRAINT PK_roster PRIMARY KEY (routeID_forRoster, departure_time)
);

CREATE TABLE train (
        trainID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        type varchar(255), 
        capacity int
);

CREATE TABLE route (
        routeID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE custodian (
        passengerID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        FOREIGN KEY (passengerID) REFERENCES passenger(passengerID)
);

CREATE TABLE conductor (
        passengerID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        FOREIGN KEY (passengerID) REFERENCES passenger(passengerID)
);

CREATE TABLE engineer (
        passengerID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        FOREIGN KEY (passengerID) REFERENCES passenger(passengerID)
);

CREATE TABLE manager (
        passengerID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        FOREIGN KEY (passengerID) REFERENCES passenger(passengerID)
);


CREATE TABLE begin_station (
        address varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
        name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT PK_begin_station PRIMARY KEY (address, name)
);

CREATE TABLE end_station (
        address varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
        name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT PK_end_station PRIMARY KEY (address, name)
);

CREATE TABLE serve (
        trainID int, 
        routeID int, 
        FOREIGN KEY (trainID) REFERENCES train(trainID), 
        FOREIGN KEY (routeID) REFERENCES route(routeID), 
        CONSTRAINT PK_serve PRIMARY KEY (trainID, routeID)
);

CREATE TABLE has (
        routeID int, 
        begin_address varchar(255), 
        begin_name varchar(255),
        end_address varchar(255), 
        end_name varchar(255),
        FOREIGN KEY (routeID) REFERENCES route(routeID), 
        FOREIGN KEY (begin_address) REFERENCES begin_station(address), 
        FOREIGN KEY (begin_name) REFERENCES begin_station(name), 
        FOREIGN KEY (end_address) REFERENCES end_station(address), 
        FOREIGN KEY (end_name) REFERENCES end_station(name), 
        CONSTRAINT PK_has PRIMARY KEY (routeID, begin_address, begin_name,      end_address, end_name)
);


CREATE TABLE edits (
        routeID_forEdits int, 
        departure_time TIME, 
        passengerID int, 
        FOREIGN KEY (routeID_forEdits) REFERENCES roster(routeID_forRoster), 
        FOREIGN KEY (departure_time) REFERENCES roster(departure_time), 
        FOREIGN KEY (passengerID) REFERENCES manager(passengerID),
        CONSTRAINT PK_serve PRIMARY KEY (routeID_forEdits, departure_time,      passengerID)
);

CREATE TABLE work_on (
        passengerID_engineer int, 
        passengerID_conductor int, 
        trainID int, 
        FOREIGN KEY (passengerID_engineer) REFERENCES engineer(passengerID),
        FOREIGN KEY (passengerID_conductor) REFERENCES conductor(passengerID),
        FOREIGN KEY (trainID) REFERENCES train(trainID),
        CONSTRAINT PK_serve PRIMARY KEY (passengerID_engineer, passengerID_conductor,       trainID)
);

CREATE TABLE works_at (
        passengerID_custodian int, 
        begin_address varchar(255), 
        begin_name varchar(255),
        end_address varchar(255),pa
        end_name varchar(255),
        FOREIGN KEY (passengerID_custodian) REFERENCES custodian(passengerID), 
        FOREIGN KEY (begin_address) REFERENCES begin_station(address), 
        FOREIGN KEY (begin_name) REFERENCES begin_station(name), 
        FOREIGN KEY (end_address) REFERENCES end_station(address), 
        FOREIGN KEY (end_name) REFERENCES end_station(name), 
        CONSTRAINT PK_has PRIMARY KEY (passengerID_custodian, begin_address,        begin_name, end_address, end_name)
);
```

Ideally, someone could provide me with a complete query that implements relational division, in a way that I could attempt to write one myself.

Thanks again for your help (and patience with a newbie)!

Comment: sure it is. in T-SQL (not sure what db engine you use), you can do SELECT 6/2
that will select 1 column with the value 3

Comment: You need to provide sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Don't link to off-site resources. Please **[edit]** your question and provide sample data and expected output as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Are you maybe referring to [tag:relational-division]?